# 'click' event only fires on first click and not second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five  elements and want something to happend when I click one of them. My code works fine when clicking for first time, but the event never hits on second click. Any idea why?

```js
$("#ratingModal").find(".star.clickable").on("click", function () {
     console.log("click");
    
     var $wrap = $(this).closest(".stars");
     var count = parseInt($(this).data("star"));
    
     $.each($wrap.find(".star"), function ($index, $itm) {
      let current = parseInt($($itm).data("star"));
    
      $($itm).removeClass("fas");
      $($itm).removeClass("far");
    
      console.log(current);
    
      if (current <= count) {
       $($itm).addClass("fas");
    
       console.log("fas");
      }
      else {
       $($itm).addClass("far");
    
       console.log("far");
      }
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="ratingModal">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="score-wrap">
      <span class="label">Score: </span>
      <div class="stars">
            <i class="fas fa-star clickable star star-1" title="1" data-star="1"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-2" title="2" data-star="2"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-3" title="3" data-star="3"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-4" title="4" data-star="4"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-5" title="5" data-star="5"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried this and it worked perfectly fine for me. Can you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Side note; the use of `prevAll()` and `nextAll()` could reduce your need for the `$.each`

Comment: yes I see it works in the snippet. so I guess there's something else wrong.

Comment: Normally when the event doesn't fire the second time it's because you're overwriting the elements that the event is attached to (eg via a `$("..").html(...)` or changing the classes that the event applies to (when using event delegation).  Your snippet does not do this and does not demonstrate the problem (ie it works fine).

Comment: after some debugging it appears that after adding a class name the event doesn't fire. if I run the code without adding "fas" or "far" as class name it fires every time

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **off().on('...')** function

```js
$("#ratingModal").find(".star.clickable").off().on("click", function () {
     console.log("click");
    
     var $wrap = $(this).closest(".stars");
     var count = parseInt($(this).data("star"));
    
     $.each($wrap.find(".star"), function ($index, $itm) {
      let current = parseInt($($itm).data("star"));
    
      $($itm).removeClass("fas");
      $($itm).removeClass("far");
    
      console.log(current);
    
      if (current <= count) {
       $($itm).addClass("fas");
    
       console.log("fas");
      }
      else {
       $($itm).addClass("far");
    
       console.log("far");
      }
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="ratingModal">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="score-wrap">
      <span class="label">Score: </span>
      <div class="stars">
            <i class="fas fa-star clickable star star-1" title="1" data-star="1"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-2" title="2" data-star="2"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-3" title="3" data-star="3"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-4" title="4" data-star="4"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star clickable star star-5" title="5" data-star="5"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: didnt make any difference